# Scaling web applications with requirejs

Tags: javascript, web-applications, requirejs

I am building a js application based on RequireJs. Everything is working fine except one thing, after compiling it with `r.js` application is around 2.5Mb.
And it does not have yet all the functionality available, i mean there is still room to work inside. And i am afraid that the compiled js file will be over 5Mb and mobile users might face some challenges on slow internet connection.

### So my question is:

> Is this normal to have such big files on very large js applications?
> Or should i split it on smaller applications/modules?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy) which splits your app into bundles, guided by your dependencies (+ cache busting, module metadata).

Comment: Thanks Nikos, i will consider this idea too. Also i fond some examples on github how to split big applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend splitting that large file in modules/files. Data transfer is not much of an issue nowadays but still, this could mean some really performance issues for some users that still dont have access to fast networks.
You should check what resources you need in order to bootstrap your app and have them loaded first, and everything else should be loaded on demand as you need them. Requirejs is a really good approach.

Comment: have you done it before ? or do you have some techniques as example on how should some parts of the app loaded on demand ?

Comment: I've mostly worked with angular and concatenated, offuscated and gzipped the entire app, but those apps where usually less than 250kb total.

Comment: I would suggest starting by separating essencial bootstrap resources from the ones that should be served on demand, and than it depends on the routing framework/library you plan to use, if you use backbone its fairly easy to do so as your routes usually point to an .js file, where you should define your required dependencies